# Is it possible to override sender name when using hipchat api to send notification?

Tags: hipchat

Looking for a way to override sender name when using hipchat api to send notification. There is a "from" (/v2/room/{room_id_or_name}/notification) parameter that appends a name to the actual username. But I want to be able to replace my username.